# Nav2 build failure: Colcon failied to build at Nav2_util

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

**Hi I am facing an issue with nav2 building using colcon build.
I use a VMware machine to run ubuntu 22(Jammy) with Ros 2 Rolling, installed using Binary install.
I face an issue with nav2_util at build stage.
The following error throws up;**

```
error: ‘typename rclcpp::Client<ServiceT>::SharedPtr rclcpp::Node::create_client(const string&, const rmw_qos_profile_t&, rclcpp::CallbackGroup::SharedPtr) [with ServiceT = lifecycle_msgs::srv::GetState; typename rclcpp::Client<ServiceT>::SharedPtr = std::shared_ptr<rclcpp::Client<lifecycle_msgs::srv::GetState> >; std::string = std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>; rmw_qos_profile_t = rmw_qos_profile_s; rclcpp::CallbackGroup::SharedPtr = std::shared_ptr<rclcpp::CallbackGroup>]’ is deprecated: use rclcpp::QoS instead of rmw_qos_profile_t [-Werror=deprecated-declarations]

47 |     client_ = node_->create_client<ServiceT>(
      |               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
   48 |       service_name,
      |       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~                          
   49 |       rmw_qos_profile_services_default,
      |       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~      
   50 |       callback_group_);
      |       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~                       
In file included from /home/ashin/ros2_rolling/ros2-linux/include/rclcpp/rclcpp/node.hpp:1594,
                 from /home/ashin/ros2_rolling/ros2-linux/include/rclcpp/rclcpp/executors/single_threaded_executor.hpp:28,
                 from /home/ashin/ros2_rolling/ros2-linux/include/rclcpp/rclcpp/executors.hpp:22,
                 from /home/ashin/ros2_rolling/ros2-linux/include/rclcpp/rclcpp/rclcpp.hpp:155,
                 from /home/ashin/nav2_ws1/src/navigation2/nav2_util/include/nav2_util/service_client.hpp:20,
                 from /home/ashin/nav2_ws1/src/navigation2/nav2_util/include/nav2_util/lifecycle_service_client.hpp:24,
                 from /home/ashin/nav2_ws1/src/navigation2/nav2_util/src/lifecycle_service_client.cpp:15:
/home/ashin/ros2_rolling/ros2-linux/include/rclcpp/rclcpp/node_impl.hpp:157:1: note: declared here
  157 | Node::create_client(
      | ^~~~
cc1plus: all warnings being treated as errors

gmake[2]: *** [src/CMakeFiles/nav2_util_core.dir/build.make:104: src/CMakeFiles/nav2_util_core.dir/lifecycle_service_client.cpp.o] Error 1

gmake[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....

gmake[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:210: src/CMakeFiles/nav2_util_core.dir/all] Error 2

gmake[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....

gmake: [Makefile:146: all] Error 2

Failed   <<< nav2_util [13.7s, exited with code 2]

Summary: 6 packages finished [17.0s]
  1 package failed: nav2_util
  2 packages had stderr output: nav2_simple_commander nav2_util
  30 packages not processed
```

*How Can resolve this issue? please help me this process.
Thank you all*

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/406790/nav2-build-failure:-colcon-failied-to-build-at-nav2_util/) by [chiyaan](https://answers.ros.org/users/56720/chiyaan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2022-09-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I may have been too quick on the draw here, please see https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation2/issues/3212 with another report. I still can't see it on my own local builds and CI doesn't report any issues using Rolling binaries on 22.04 bare metal, but seems like the warning can be easily resolved and won't impact anything so we can make that warning fix if one of you two can test it out and let me know it solves the issue at hand.

Sorry about that -- can't bat a thousand :-)

---

Originally posted by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) with karma: 8272 on 2022-09-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [chiyaan](https://answers.ros.org/users/56720/chiyaan/) on 2022-09-22**:
Hi Steve, thanks again for your support.
Sure I am working on it and will get back to you.

**Comment by [chiyaan](https://answers.ros.org/users/56720/chiyaan/) on 2022-09-23**:
Hi Steve. It has worked.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Did you install the dependencies for the Nav2 repository?

```
rosdep install -y -r -q --from-paths src --ignore-src --rosdistro humble
colcon build --symlink-install
```

Is your repository on the correct branch and is it updated to the latest commit?

This can also be helpful:

- https://navigation.ros.org/build_instructions/build_docs/build_troubleshooting_guide.html#build-troubleshooting-guide

Especially:

> Make sure you’re using the correct
> branch for your distribution. There is
> no cross support from branch for
> DistroA in DistroB. The main
> development branch uses the Rolling
> distribution.

---

Originally posted by [ljaniec](https://answers.ros.org/users/63587/ljaniec/) with karma: 3064 on 2022-09-21

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [chiyaan](https://answers.ros.org/users/56720/chiyaan/) on 2022-09-21**:
Hi @ ljaniec Thank you for your reply.
Yes I did install dependencies for rolling distro..Dependencies were all installed successfully.During colcon build ,one particular package Nav2_util was were failure occured.